# Enviar cookie al servidor con Volley i Android

Tags: android, cookies, android-volley

Estoy intentando crear una app que se comunica con un servidor con php. Con la libreria Volley he conseguido validar el usuario del aplicativo web i recibir cookie con la id de la PHPSESSID.

Lo que no consigo de ninguna forma es hacer una peticion a alguno de los archivos php del servidor y que me reconozca la session creada.

El código que he provado despues de buscar mucho por internet es este. El header carga la session con el contenido PHPSESSID=kdlksajljsadsajd; path=/; Pero no hay forma de que el servidor me devuelve el contenido de otro archivo de la web que no sea el de login... Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? Que seguramente seran unas cuantas cosas...
Gracias por adelanatado!

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Usuari, Password;
Button LoginButton;
String UsuariHolder, PasswordHolder;
ProgressBar progressBarLogin;
ProgressBar progressBarDades;
Boolean CheckEditText;
Switch recordar;


private String rawCookies;
private static final String SESSION_COOKIE = "sessionid";
private static final String COOKIE_KEY = "Cookie";
private static LoginActivity _instance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    _instance = this;

    
    Usuari = findViewById(R.id.editText_Usuari);
    Password = findViewById(R.id.editText_Password);
    LoginButton =  findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    progressBarLogin = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
    progressBarDades = findViewById(R.id.progressBarTorns);
    progressBarDades.setMax(10);
    recordar = findViewById(R.id.switchLogin);

    
    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

        if (CheckEditText) {
            UserLogin();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Emplena tots els camps.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public void UserLogin() {

 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
         ServerResponse -> {

             progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             consulta();
         },
         volleyError -> {
             progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.toast_senseConexio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("login", UsuariHolder);
            params.put("password", PasswordHolder);
            return params;
        }

     @Override
     protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
         
         assert response.headers != null;
         Log.i("response",response.headers.toString());
         Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
         rawCookies = responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie");
         Log.i("cookies",rawCookies);
         consulta();
         return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
     }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

}

public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {

    UsuariHolder = Usuari.getText().toString().trim();
    PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString().trim();
    CheckEditText = !TextUtils.isEmpty(UsuariHolder) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder);
}

public void consulta(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            ServerResponse -> {

               progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(ServerResponse);

                    // Matching server responce message to our text.
                    JSONObject dades = array.getJSONObject(0);
                    if(dades.getString("data").equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {

                        // Tanquem l'actual Activity i obrim l'aplicació
                        finish();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, dades.getString("data"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            },
            volleyError -> {
                progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.toast_senseConexio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }) {
        
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

            if (headers == null
                    || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
                headers = new HashMap<>();
            }

            LoginActivity.get().addSessionCookie(headers);

            return headers;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

public static LoginActivity get() {
    return _instance;
}

public final void addSessionCookie(Map<String, String> headers) {
    String sessionId = rawCookies;
    if (sessionId.length() > 0) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(SESSION_COOKIE);
        builder.append("=");
        builder.append(sessionId);
        if (headers.containsKey(COOKIE_KEY)) {
            builder.append("; ");
            builder.append(headers.get(COOKIE_KEY));
        }
        headers.put(COOKIE_KEY, builder.toString());
    }
}
}
```